# The connection to the server 10.0.x.x:6443 was refused after restarting the VM where kubernetes master was installed using kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, kubectl, kubeadm

I installed a Kubernetes master using kubeadm sucessfully on a VM (VirtualBox). The problem is that if I stop the machine and restart it the master node seems to be down:

```
kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 10.0.x.x:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

How can I make sure it will always be up after restarting the VM?

**UPDATE:**

After restarting VM this is what I have to do to make the master node start:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo systemctl restart kubelet.service
```

Why? How can I fix it so that it starts without having to input that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem is that if I stop the machine and restart it the master node seems to be down

- Since it was kubeadm installation that worked properly before restarts, seems like Env var is missing after restart. Try to run this before `kubectl get nodes`:

  ```
  export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
  ```

  If it starts normally, then you need to make sure that `KUBECONFIG` environment variable is properly configured upon restart either adding it to `.bashrc` or similar...

#### Edited:

> Why? How can I fix it so that it starts without having to input that?

- Ah, swap file is teasing you. By default kubelet will not start if swap is enabled. You have two options:

  - **Remove swap**: That's easy, just disable it as you already listed but make it permanent by commenting swap line in `/etc/fstab` file. Add `#` before line creating swap mount point and next time you restart you won't have it.
  - **Allow kubelet to run with swap enabled**: I know, not recommended by documentation, but if you like to live dangerous, you can add/edit in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` following line:

    ```
    Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false"
    ```

    and next restart you will be able to run kubelet with swap enabled.

Comment: Great! Updated answer to reflect it

Comment: Thanks Const, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem fixed by clearing some space on the HDD. It seems that the space is low. Then, I restarted the server and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where the `kubectl` commands are working in my master node but the same executed in slave node give me this error:

> The connection to the server 10.0.x.x:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

The solution that worked for me is as below:

I copied the `$KUBECONFIG` file of Master and places in the slave nodes `.kube/` location and it worked (I have only 2 nodes, one master and one slave.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to kill kubelet service and restart again. pods and container will be running as well as before reboot.

```
pkill kubelet
```

and

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

good luck